# Android bindService returns false when trying to connect to 2 services

Tags: android, android-service, locationlistener

I know there have been others that have asked similar questions, but I haven't been able to get an answer on how to get past a false when calling bindService.

Basically I've written an app which is connected to 2 services. They're both in my manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.test.LService"></service>
<service android:name="com.test.CService"></service>
```

The CService works as expected and always has. I added the LService yesterday and it won't start at all. Note that originally I had my LocationListener imeplement in MainActivity, but I wanted to collect GPS coords independent of the Activity being in focus. To save space, I'll just paste in LService related code since it's the service I'm having trouble with. In my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // bindService for LService always returns FALSE?!?!
    Log.d(TAG, "LService: " + this.context.bindService(new Intent(this, LService.class), mLConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE));
    Log.d(TAG, "CService: " + this.context.bindService(new Intent(this, CService.class), mCConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE));
}

private ServiceConnection mLocConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        LocBinder binder = (LocBinder) service;
        mLocService = binder.getService();
        mLocBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        mLocBound = false;
    }
};
```

In the LService class, all the binding stuff you'd expect:

```
private final IBinder mBinder = new LBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public class LBinder extends Binder {
    public LService getService() {
        return LService.this;
    }
}
```

The only thing that could be an issue is that my LService implements LocationListener:

```
public class LocService extends Service implements LocationListener {
...
```

CService doesn't implement anything, it just extends Service like it should. Do you think removing LocationListener as an implement, and re-implementing it in a sub-class would do the trick? Could it be some Android reflection seeing the implement and determining that it's not suitable as a Service? Why no exception though? Any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Well it's not because of the LocationListener implementation. I removed the implement from LService and it's still returning FALSE. Sigh...

**UPDATE2:** Trying to debug the situation is rough, but the CService drops into ClassLoader while the LService doesn't at all. Is it possible there's an incorrect some class identifier somewhere?!? Everything looks ok to me.

**UPDATE3:** I gave up and just merged the LocationListener into my CService service... I'll close this question when I can.

Answer (score 0):

I can't close this question so I'll just answer with what I ended up doing.

I gave up and just merged the LocationListener into my CService service and gave up on trying to figure out why my 2nd service wouldn't work. Still interested in opinions though!

Comment: I was going to say try doing startService() first and then binding to it. You should be allowed to bind to it even after you start it.